# php Update sql and Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to do a query in php, output the data on the page and then modify it in the database.

How do I do that?

Currently I do it like this but it dose not work:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pics WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $dir = $row["dir"];
       $likes = $row["likes"];
    }

$sqlq = "UPDATE pics SET likes='$likes+1' WHERE id='$id'";

$conn->query($sqlq);

$conn->close();
```

But the like dose not add to the database.

Comment: In what way does this fail?  Are there any errors in the PHP logs?  Why aren't you checking for errors from the database queries?

Comment: your update failed

Comment: There is no error log. Everything works, just that when I look at the database, the likes value is not modified. And its not modified on the page either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you echo your $sqlq out using

```
echo $sqlq;
```

you'll see that the `'$likes+1'` isn't doing what you expect.

You could really simplify it by doing

```
$sqlq = "UPDATE pics SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id='$id'";
```

which removes any risk of two users updating the database at teh same time overwriting each other.

But you should really check out using "parameterized queries" as that would solve all your problems (and may your queries safer). Check the examples in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: You're welcome. If you took the "quick fix" please spend 5 minutes later looking at the parametized query (bind-param) link to make your code safer and easier to read / debug.